# round a input at 2 decimal with comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code which works with a dot but I want it to work with a comma as well.

Here is my code

```
$(function() {
  $('input').on('input', function() {
    this.value = this.value
      .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')             // numbers and decimals only
      .replace(/(^[\d]{4})[\d]/g, '$1')   // not more than 2 digits at the beginning
      .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')         // decimal can't exist more than once
      .replace(/(\.[\d]{2})./g, '$1');    // not more than 4 digits after decimal
  });
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7g36hzf/2/)

thanks in advance

*--EDIT--*

Sorry for the wrong fiddle

[This one works](https://jsfiddle.net/z7g36hzf/5/) with dot but not with comma.

Comment: You can use `toFixed` method instead of regex https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: It doesn't work with `.` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you do not need to use Regular Expressions, just parse the value as a Number/float and use the `toFixed()` method.

```
var rounded = parseFloat(input.value.replace(/,/g, '.')).toFixed(2);
```

So I forgot to take into account that you also would like to support commas. Just replace them with a dot and youre done.

To display the input as given, you could do something like that:

```
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var cleaned = this.value.replace([^\d,.], ''),
      hasCommas = /,/g.test(cleaned),
      parsed = parseFloat(cleaned.replace(/,/g, '.')),
      val = isNaN(parsed) ? this.value : parsed.toFixed(2);

  if (isNaN(parsed)) { /*do something with invalid input*/ }
  elseif (hasCommas) { this.value = val.replace(/\./g, ',') }
  else { this.value = val }

}
```

**UPDATE**

If I am getting this right, than you would like to »extract« a number from arbitrary input, so I added a line to delete all characters which are not a digit, a comma, or a dot. Anyway, in case of multiple commas/dots, the input is not a valid number and to pick the first valid out of that does not make much sense, since the program does not know which number the user meant to enter.

Comment: thanks for your help but it does nt work with comma , i just need to put the comma or dot with numbers in my function

Answer (score 0):

Without using regex, and keeping it simple...

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input'), 
    btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  var nocomma = input.value.split(',').join(''), 
      rounded = parseFloat(nocomma).toFixed(2), 
      final = (+rounded).toLocaleString('en-us', {useGrouping: true});

  console.log(final);
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="1,245,345.5673" />
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Go" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss comma on the first replace, it should be `\d.,` not `\d.` so

```
.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, '') // numbers, dot and comma only
```

and on the last replace add for comma too `\.` and `\,`

```
.replace(/(\,.*)\,/g, '$1') // comma once only
.replace(/(\,[\d]{2})./g, '$1') // two digit after comma only
```

so here are the complete replace

```
.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, '')  
.replace(/(^[\d]{4})[\d]/g, '$1')
.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1') 
.replace(/(\,.*)\,/g, '$1')
.replace(/(\.[\d]{2})./g, '$1')
.replace(/(\,[\d]{2})./g, '$1');
```

but may be this is not the best practice, you can refer to this [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) about regex. There are lot of pattern and its tools.